# Understanding WadeShuler's IPN fork

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

Wondering if anyone here has used [WadeShuler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2703135/wade-shuler)'s [IPN fork](https://github.com/WadeShuler/PHP-PayPal-IPN). Its very unclear to me, and was wondering if we could see this a bit.

1. I created 3 files api_cert_chain.crt, ipnlistener.php and ipn.php and uploaded to my domain.com/ location.
2. Changed paths in ipnlistener.php & ipn.php. They are now : `require_once( 'IpnListener.php');` and `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/api_cert_chain.crt');` since I am using all files at the same location.
3. I have `namespace wadeshuler\paypalipn;` and `use wadeshuler\paypalipn\IpnListener;` in the two files respectively. Do I need to create a folder wadeshuler ? And why are the slashes reversed ?
4. In ipn.php, it would have been good to finish it with error handling and database updating // this is rather a feature request.
5. I have loaded ipn.php both via paypal button via actual payment and directly, I have nothing in either ipn_success.log or ipn_error.log

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have nothing in either log, either your ipn.php script isn't getting called, or your ipn.php script is crashing before it completes.

Firstly check the notify_url you are giving to Paypal, something like notify_url=http://www.*your-domain*.com/ipn.php. Ideally you should plug that URL into [Paypal's IPN Simulator](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/ipn_simulator), and see if it talks to your script or not.

If the IPN simulator gets a failure talking to your script and the address is correct, likely you've introduced a bug. See if any PHP errors are being logged on your web server - by default my host throws them all to a file called "error_log", in the directory the script is running in.

There's not much else that should be able to go wrong, Wade's module is pretty straight forward and should just work, so long as you've made no errors in any of the paths you have needed to change.

Comment: Using Paypal's IPN simulator, I get an empty array in ipn_error.log. Calling this page via paypal button, I get nothing returned in either the success or error log, though I get confirmation email from paypal that payment has been processes.

Comment: An empty log is tricky, something is going wrong, weird that nothing specific is logged. I would try logging additional info yourself at other points in the script, so you can see what is in specific data (such as the POST data), or even just check which parts of the IpnListener class are being executed. Also check that sandbox isn't set to true in the ipn script - it's the default, and won't work for real world transactions. The Paypal email confirms the transaction took place, the IPN is the extra notification to your app - the transaction is still valid even if the IPN process fails.

Comment: Meanwhile I saw your other post on this where you posted your code, and that helped me to debug this. Thanks, its working now. One question, if I want to have a drop down to select the amount, instead of sending the amount via a hidden field. Any idea ?

Comment: You could make it part of a form, and after you get the values posted back, you could redirect to the Paypal link with the values you collected. Tricky to otherwise link directly in PHP with dynamic data. You might also see if Paypal have another interface, particularly if there's anything that lets you submit POST data directly (I don't know if they do, I only use direct links myself currently).

Comment: Means to have an hidden interface in between, yes this is an excellent idea. I was trying to get a solution directly using a paypal form and I was finding a solution this way. Thanks Peter.